# Question about the counter diabatic(CD) term in Digitized Adiabatic Quantum Computing

Tags: annealing, adiabatic-model

Recently I have read two articles about the Digitized Adiabatic Quantum Computing(DAQC), and tried to factorize $35=5\times7$ and $2479=67\times37$.
But some problems came when trying to solve the coefficient of the CD term.

#### problems for 35

In section IV of the paper ["Shortcuts to Adiabaticity in Digitized Adiabatic Quantum Computing"](https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.03539), there is a result about the variational coefficient $\alpha_1$, which is
$$\alpha_1=\frac{1}{4}\frac{h^2_z+J^2_0}{\lambda^2(h_z^4J_0^4+3h_z^2J^2_0)+(1-\lambda)^2h_x^2(h_z^2+4J_0^2)},$$
with $H_{init}=\sum h_x^j\sigma_x^j, H_{final}=\sum (h_z^j\sigma_z^j+J_0\sigma_z^j\sigma_z^{j+1}), \sigma^{N+1}=\sigma^{0}$.

However, for the simplest example with $N=2, H_{final}=\frac{1}{4}(\sigma_z^0\sigma_z^1+\sigma_z^1\sigma_z^0), h_z=0,J_0=\frac{1}{4}$, I get $$\alpha_1=-\frac{1}{\lambda^2+16(1-\lambda)^2h_x^2}.$$It works for my code to factorize $35$, but it doesn't fit the expression above.

#### problems for 2479

Moreover, in the paragrah after equation (10) of the paper ["Digitized-Adiabatic Quantum Factorization"](https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.09480), it provides $$\alpha_1=\frac{0.0830}{h_x^2(1-\lambda)^2+5.0112\lambda^2},$$while $H_{final}$ defined in equation (8).

With $$H_0=(1-\lambda)H_{init}+\lambda H_{final}, A\approx i\alpha_1[H_0,\partial_\lambda H_0]=i\alpha_1[H_{init},H_{final}],\\G=\partial_\lambda H_0+i[A,H_0],\alpha_1=\text{argmin}\text{Tr}(G^2)$$ I get a similar but different $\alpha_1^*\approx -\alpha_1$
$$\alpha^*_1=-\frac{185/2228}{h_x^2(\lambda-1)+5.0112\lambda^2}\approx -\alpha_1.$$

#### question

It looks like that there are some terrible mistakes about $\alpha_1$, I tried checking my results of $\alpha_1$ with the symbolic operation of Octave but got nothing.

Maybe I did something wrong before I solve the equations $\alpha_1=\text{argmin}\text{Tr}(G^2)$?

Or is there any general expressions of $\alpha_1$ so that I can easily find my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

With help from Narendra N. Hegade and Yongcheng Ding I succeed in finding out my mistake.

Narendra advices me to do some other examples like $2893=11*263$ and point out that we may use similar but different $\alpha$, Yongcheng tells me the same thing and suggests me to check the process of applying the matrice to the circuit construction.

For any $H_{init}=\sum h_x\sigma_x$ with the ground state $|+\rangle^n$, here is $h_x<0$. Thus I can directly deduce the CD term with the form of $H_{final}$. However I make a mistake about $\sigma_x\sigma_z=-i\sigma_y=\sigma_z\sigma_x$, and create a wrong local quantum circuit about CD term.

Finally I got some results different from those in the referred articles, but work.